# i want to split (10.12345, 70.12345)

Tags: angularjs

i tried to split that but i get this output on console

lattitude :-- (10.12345

longitude :-- 70.12345)

i want this as output --

lattitude :-- 10.12345

longitude :-- 70.12345

here is my piece of code ==

```
             var latlngStr = input.toString().split(',',2);

             var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])};

             console.log("lattitude :-- "+latlngStr[0]);
             console.log("longitude :-- "+latlngStr[1]);

             console.log("actualdata : "+latlngStr);
             console.log(+status);
             $scope.geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
               if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
               {
                 if (results[1])
                 {
                   map.setZoom(11);
                   infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
                   infowindow.open(map, $scope.pin);
                 } else
                 {
                   window.alert('No results found');
                 }
               } else
               {
                 //window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' +status);
               }
             });
           }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input.toString().replace('(','').replace(')','').split(',',2);`

Comment: thank you for your reply mr.Sameer, your answer worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
input.toString().substring(1, input.length-1).split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

`event.latLng` is a **LatLng** object which i'm converting to a string is unnecessarily. we can also use the object's native methods:

```
var lat = event.latLng.lat(); 
var lng = event.latLng.lng();
```